# Error creating SAX parser

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports

I am using JasperReports and I am hitting an exception when I am trying to generate an html page hosted by my tomcat server.

The line:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(
"C:/Documents and Settings/axc1888/workspace/OATS/WebContent/status.jrxml");
```

ends up with the exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Error creating SAX parser
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.createParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:108)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createParser(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1338)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory.createDigester(JRXmlDigesterFactory.java:1313)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:205)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:170)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:154)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:146)
  ...

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage
  at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.getProperty(XmlReader.java:181)
  at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.setProperty(XmlReader.java:166)
  at gnu.xml.aelfred2.JAXPFactory$JaxpParser.setProperty(JAXPFactory.java:147)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.configureParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:139)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRReportSaxParserFactory.createParser(JRReportSaxParserFactory.java:103)
  ... 8 more
```

I believe it has something to do with server paths...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I have added the xerces.jar into my project (http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=46889)

Comment: Also wanted to mention, I had a JasperReports project set up without a tomcat server, but it seems that once I moved the code + jar's over to my project with tomcat, it throws the exception.

Comment: Update: The xerces.jar fixed the exception. I guess my eclipse was out of sync for a little bit and I began searching for different xerces jars.

Comment: It seems that you have 2 different SAX Parsers on your path, xerces and gnujaxp (Aelfred). For details on which parser will be used, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798366/how-do-i-find-out-which-jaxp-implementation-is-in-use-and-where-it-was-loaded-fr. In my experience, Aelfred does not always support all features, so I recommend you remove the gnujaxp.jar file from your project.

Answer (score 0):

you have add a duplicate xml api (.jar) ,

## remove all xml regarding jars.

i had  that problem, i just remove all jars then added only neccessory jars..