# Restlet client on Java 1.7 xml parse error "FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING: Cannot set the feature to false when security manager is present."

Tags: java, security, restlet, xerces

**EDIT : 31/OCT/2014 [The fix for this is now available](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/785) in both Restlet 2.2 and master (future 2.3) branches**

Our Netbeans Platform Restlet client app runs okay on Java 1.6 but with 1.7.0_11, I get security runtime errors.

Is there a easy way to prevent this?

```
WARN org.restlet.log():241 - Unable to unmarshal the XML representation
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create customized SAX source
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING: Cannot set the feature to false when security manager is present.]
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.java:201)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getObject(JaxbRepresentation.java:417)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbConverter.toObject(JaxbConverter.java:172)
            at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:167)
            at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:828)
            at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:240)
            <SNIP>
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING: Cannot set the feature to false when security manager is present.
            at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:122)
            at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.java:190)
            ... 23 more
```

In both java runtimes, my System.getSecurityManager()
  is a instance of org.netbeans.TopSecurityManager

### EDIT 1

After a bit more research into Restlet source as mentioned in answer from Simon Lehmann I see `JaxbConverter.java` invokes

```
new JaxbRepresentation<T>(Representation source, Class<T> target).getObject();
```

Then ...

```
public JaxbRepresentation(Representation xmlRepresentation, Class<T> type) { ...}
```

Then ...

```
public JaxbRepresentation(Representation xmlRepresentation, String contextPath, ValidationEventHandler validationHandler, ClassLoader classLoader) {
    super((xmlRepresentation == null) ? null : xmlRepresentation
            .getMediaType());
    this.classLoader = classLoader;
    this.contextPath = contextPath;
    this.object = null;
    this.validationEventHandler = validationHandler;
    this.xmlRepresentation = xmlRepresentation;
}
```

In this particular constructor, `this.secureProcessing` always remains false so later we get errors with Java 7 secure processing feature of the XML parser if there is any security manager present.

Not sure if this is a bug in restlet or if I am doing something wrong ?

### EDIT 2 (Simple Java 7 app vs one in full app)

I wrote small restlet client test program on 1.7.0_11 which works ok with our server. I am guessing in my full client app that there is something 'bad' in the classpath ?

In both the small app and the full app I [print the factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798366/how-do-i-find-out-which-jaxp-implementation-is-in-use-and-where-it-was-loaded-fr) and it is same in both :

```
 [exec] DocumentBuilderFactory implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl loaded from: Java Runtime
 [exec] XPathFactory implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl loaded from: Java Runtime
 [exec] TransformerFactory implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl loaded from: Java Runtime
 [exec] SAXParserFactory implementation: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl loaded from: Java Runtime
```

I switch on extra JAXP logging  via System.setProperty("jaxp.debug", "true");  and see it is different in each :

---

Small working app

```
[junit] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
[junit] JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
[junit] JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null

[junit] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory
[junit] JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
[junit] JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
[junit] JAXP: using thread context class loader (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6c5bdfae) for search
[junit] JAXP: Looking up system property 'javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom'
[junit] JAXP: The property is undefined.
[junit] JAXP: found null in $java.home/jaxp.properties
[junit] JAXP: no META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory file was found
[junit] JAXP: attempting to use the platform default W3C DOM XPath lib
[junit] JAXP: createInstance(com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl)
[junit] JAXP: loaded com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl from jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/jaxp/XPathFactoryImpl.class
[junit] JAXP: factory 'com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl' was found for http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom

[junit] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
[junit] JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
[junit] JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
```

---

Full Netbeans app (failing)

```
 [exec] JAXP: using thread context class loader (SystemClassLoader[420 modules]) for search
 [exec] JAXP: Looking up system property 'javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom'
 [exec] JAXP: The property is undefined.
 [exec] JAXP: found null in $java.home/jaxp.properties
 [exec] JAXP: no META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory file was found
 [exec] JAXP: attempting to use the platform default W3C DOM XPath lib
 [exec] JAXP: createInstance(com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl)
 [exec] JAXP: loaded com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl from jar:file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar!/com/sun/org/apache/xpath/internal/jaxp/XPathFactoryImpl.class
 [exec] JAXP: factory 'com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl' was found for http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom
 [exec] JAXP: find factoryId =javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
 [exec] JAXP: found jar resource=META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory using ClassLoader: SystemClassLoader[420 modules]
 [exec] JAXP: loaded from fallback value: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl
 [exec] JAXP: created new instance of class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl using ClassLoader: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem - exactly - when I upgraded from restlet 2.2m1 running on Java 6 to restlet 2.2m5 running on Java 7.

The solution I resorted to was to initialize the secureProcessor flag in the JaxbRepresentation  constructor you mentioned to true (and rebuild the restlet code). That resolved the problem for me.  It is not clear if the lack of initialization of the secureProcessing flag in that constructor is intentional or is an oversight.

I filed a bug about it:
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/785

Comment: I will watch the Restlet issue you raised! Hopefully Restlets team can respond to it.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems, JDK 7 (Oracle as well as OpenJDK/IcedTea) has added a check to prevent disabling the so called [secure processing feature](http://jaxp.java.net/1.4/JAXP-Compatibility.html#JAXP_security) of the XML parser if there is any security manager present. This feature is meant to prevent denial of service attacks, for example by providing a SOAP message with deeply nested entity definitions. Unfortunately, they have opted to [disable control over this feature in general](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/SAXParserFactoryImpl.java?av=f#113) when a security manager is found instead of allowing you to configure it via [security permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html).

However, the [restlet code which tries to set this feature to false](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.ext.jaxb/src/org/restlet/ext/jaxb/internal/Unmarshaller.java#L190) is actually using the [`secureProcessing` property of the JaxbRepresentation](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet.ext.jaxb/src/org/restlet/ext/jaxb/JaxbRepresentation.java#L499), which should be set to true by default and thus, should not cause any exception.

So the only adivce I could give you is to try updating the restlet library, as maybe the default settings or something else related to this has changed.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I am using latest stable Restlet release i.e. 2.1.1; it worked okay with older Restlets on JDK 7 before I think the following change was incorporated 
https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/commit/ec692bd3b5e386261413210191b179fec22b6cd2#modules
I currently investigating why the JaxbRepresentation's secureProcessing is false for me ...

Comment: (FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING does more than an attempt at DoS protection.)

Comment: Well, ok, it also disables the XPath extension functions, but those have nothing to do with DOM or SAX parsers. To my knowledge, all other effects of secure processing are limitations on the number of things that may be in a document. What other purpose does this have than preventing DoS attacks?