# Restlet 2.1.RC1 + Java 1.7 as a Netbeans 7.x app module works ok ; upgrading to Restlet 2.1.2 give runtime error (FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING)

Tags: restlet

Restlet 2.1.RC1 works fine but upgrading to 2.1.2 gives :

```
   WARN - Unable to unmarshal the XML representation 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Unable to create customized SAX source
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING: Cannot set the feature to false when security manager is present.]
  at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.internal.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Unmarshaller.java:201)
  at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbRepresentation.getObject(JaxbRepresentation.java:417)
  at org.restlet.ext.jaxb.JaxbConverter.toObject(JaxbConverter.java:172)
  at org.restlet.service.ConverterService.toObject(ConverterService.java:170)
  at org.restlet.resource.Resource.toObject(Resource.java:828)
  at org.restlet.engine.resource.ClientInvocationHandler.invoke(ClientInvocationHandler.java:240)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.getServerInformation(Unknown Source)
```

I confess a while ago I posted a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705003/restlet-client-on-java-1-7-xml-parse-error-feature-secure-processing-cannot-se) - but in that one I focused on the issue that

Restlet  2.1.2 + **Java 1.6** as a Netbeans 7.x app  works.

But changing java to Java 1.7 gives above error so I think this question is not a duplicate as here I am focusing on Restlet 2.1.RC1 ==> 2.1.2.

As mention in other question I suspect [this change](https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/commit/ec692bd3b5e386261413210191b179fec22b6cd2#modules) is related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eventual workaround was the code hack described in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19230016/449347

See the bug raised at https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/785