# NiFi 1.2 TransformXML jar file

Tags: xslt, saxon, apache-nifi

I'm running NiFi 1.2.0 and would like to replace the default XSLT engine with something else? i.e. saxon9he.jar? I've copied this jar into the lib directory and restarted NiFi, but I see no references in the log it's being used?

Comment: I am on Apache Nifi 1.3 and it has saxon. Why do you want to upload your own..? > ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.3.0.nar-unpacked/META-INF/bundled-dependencies/Saxon-HE-9.6.0-5.jar What is your objective..?

Comment: To find out what implementation is being used, try setting the `jaxp.debug` system property (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798366/how-do-i-find-out-which-jaxp-implementation-is-in-use-and-where-it-was-loaded-fr), or edit a call of `system-property('xsl:vendor')` into one of the stylesheets.

Comment: I was hoping to utilize some of the new features in SaxonHE9-8-0-2J

Comment: you can use ExecuteScript/groovy processor where you can define custom classpath and do what you need with custom code.